# value animator gives largest possible value immediately

Tags: android, android-animation

I have value animator and I'm trying to animate views in my activity and it's working perfectly on many devices i had tested on except Galaxy Note 3
when I run my code on it gives me the largest possible value

here is my code with the log

```
public void slide_down(Context ctx, final View v) {
  Log.d("valueAnimator","slide_down");
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  AddEventActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
  final int hight = dm.heightPixels;
  ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, hight - convertDpToPixel(228));
  va.setDuration(250);
  Log.d("valueAnimator","hight "+hight);
  Log.d("valueAnimator","va "+(hight - convertDpToPixel(228)));
  va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
    v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
    v.requestLayout();
    Log.d("valueAnimator","value "+value);
   }
  });
  va.start();
 }
```

and the log

```
    D/valueAnimator(29832): slide_down
 D/valueAnimator(29832): hight 1920
 D/valueAnimator(29832): va 1236
 D/valueAnimator(29832): value 1236
```

log from galaxy s4 device (the normal state)

```
    D/valueAnimator(22319): slide_down
D/valueAnimator(22319): hight 1920
D/valueAnimator(22319): va 1236
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 0
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 0
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 52
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 113
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 200
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 306
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 419
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 548
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 672
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 801
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 922
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1023
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1113
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1180
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1220
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1235
D/valueAnimator(22319): value 1236
```

Comment: your device is too slow maybe?  tried with longer duration?

Comment: where and when are you printing out this line?  D/valueAnimator(29832): value 1236. The best time to do that would be in the onAnimationUpdate method you have shown above.

Comment: i updated my question the previous code was not complete

Comment: tried with longer duration? also try to log animated fraction

Comment: and what is animated fraction?

Comment: i'm animating a relative layout